# Coloring nodes by class (and adding class as a vdim) in Holoviews with networkx and bokeh

Tags: python, networkx, bokeh, holoviews

so I am trying to color my nodes according to categories, lets say `categories = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

```
for comb in data:
    edges.append((comb['comb'][0], comb['comb'][1], comb['count']))
      
graph = hv.Graph(edges, vdims='weight') 
graph = layout_nodes(graph, layout=nx.layout.fruchterman_reingold_layout, kwargs={'weight': 'weight'})
nodes_array = graph.nodes.array()
for node in nodes_array:
    (node) #add vdim to node here and set node_color to this vdim?
labels = hv.Labels(([i[0] for i in nodes_array], [i[1] for i in nodes_array], [i[2] for i in nodes_array]))

(graph.opts(width=800, height=800, node_color='weight')*labels.opts(text_font_size='8pt', text_color='blue'))
```

what I need is a way to do this, I imagine I need to set category for every node, somehow define it as a vdim and then set node_color to this vdim?

I saw other questions about specific nodes and similar, but I dont think I can define the nodes (including position) as I need the `fruchterman_reingold_layout` to do this for me.

(Bonus if there is a way to change size of node also)

edit:
So, what I also tried was adding a dimension via `add_dimension` as shown in the documentation here: http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Dimensioned_Containers.html

`graph.nodes.add_dimension('weight', dim_pos=3, dim_val=['a'] * 457)`
457 ist the number of my nodes, so that is right, but I get the following error:
`ValueError: kdims: list length must be between 3 and 3 (inclusive)`
also I dont exactly know what to do with the result of the function, I guess set it as new nodes somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question as I found a way to achieve the result I wanted.
Its more a workaround than a clean solution but it works, so might be helpfull to others until there is a better answer.

```
from holoviews.element.graphs import layout_nodes
import random
G = hv.Graph([
    ('a', 'b', 3),
    ('a', 'c', 0.2),
    ('c', 'd', 0.1),
    ('c', 'e', 0.7),
    ('c', 'f', 5),
    ('a', 'd', 0.3)
], vdims=['weight'])

G = layout_nodes(G, layout=nx.layout.fruchterman_reingold_layout, kwargs={'weight': 'weight'})
nodes_array = G.nodes.array()
newNodes_array = []
for node in nodes_array:
    newNodes_array.append((node[0], node[1], node[2], random.choice(['class1', 'class2', 'class3'])))
N = hv.Nodes(newNodes_array, vdims='class')

labels = hv.Labels(([i[0] for i in nodes_array], [i[1] for i in nodes_array], [i[2] for i in nodes_array]))
G*(N).opts(color = 'class', cmap='Set1')*labels
```

The `G.nodes.array()` gets copied after the required `nx.layout.fruchterman_reingold_layout` is applied, so it is then possible to add a new dimension to these nodes and plot them along with the graph.
Output:

[image: Output Graph]